# localhost programs not woking in windows safari's browser. why?

Tags: safari, ionic3

my app is based on ionic framework(ionic3). in all browser, it's working but in safari browser, it's not working (safari browser installed in windows os but other URL working in safari except localhost.

Comment: please add your console logs so we could help you

Comment: in console log it showing that viewport argument key "viewport-fit" not recognized